# Use ExoPlayer Without External Storage Permissions

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, exoplayer

I have an Android app made with **Xamarin Forms** that uses ExoPlayer to play both streaming and local videos. When `.mp4` files are downloaded by the app, they are saved to internal storage (`Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal`) and never to an external location such as an SD card.

I want to limit the permissions that the app requires and I do not want to add READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. In other parts of the app I have successfully written and read files to internal storage without adding any external storage permissions.

I am unable to load my `.mp4` file into ExoPlayer unless I add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` (or the `WRITE` version) to `AndroidManifest.xml`. ExoPlayer will show me a "Permission to access storage was denied" toast and refuse to play the video. I believe that ExoPlayer is testing for the existence of the external storage permission even though I don't believe it is needed, and exiting without actually trying to play the video.

How can I coerce ExoPlayer into playing the video without testing for the external storage permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are making a call to the `MaybeRequestReadExternalStoragePermission` method. The `MaybeRequestReadExternalStoragePermission` method is responsible for making sure the App has the permissions to access the external storage. The ExoPlayer doesn't handle this internally but assumes the App developer calls this method if the App need to access content from the external storage.

See the implementation: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/000f3f23056aae30a98ac74fb30e484844548b3e/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/util/Util.java#L159

Make sure you don't call the `MaybeRequestReadExternalStoragePermission` method from your source code (usually this is done in the `PlayerActivity` class, from the `InitializePlayer` method). Now you can also remove the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` from the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Note that if you do try to access the external storage without having the permissions you app will crash.